# Get EN,IT,FR,DE,ES Localized City name from google api

Tags: ios, iphone, google-api, google-places-api

In my ios app i'm using this call to get an autocomplete function

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=%@&types=(cities)&key=%s
```

After that i use another call to retrive details of a place starting by his placeid:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=%@&key=%s&language=en&oe=utf8
```

Now i need to store in my app the city name in localized format (english,italian,french,spanish). I think that i can made a localized place-detail each language i wanna support but i would like to retrive this information with the minimum number of requests. There's a way to get all the localized name of a city starting by his placeid?

Comment: There is some information ont his thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464788/google-maps-api-v3-5-geocoder-language-option

Comment: thank you but the thread don't show how to pass multiple language in the language option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong on this, but it seems like you can only set one lanugage in the language parameter. Yet, even with that you should be able to make multiple calls like

```
var langIDs = ["en","it","fr","de","es"];
for(var langID in langIDs){ 
url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=34.431741,135.392299&destination=34.631741,135.992299&sensor=false&language=" + langIDs[langID]+ "&";
}
```

Note, I did not test the code.

Thank

Comment: yes it is also my conclusion after some other googling... so i'll mark your answer as correct, until and if someone will find another solution